# How to calculate values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, element, attr

I have a little problem Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LK7Tj/3/

```
var result = parseFloat($(".val1").val()) + parseFloat($(".val2").val());
```

For now script work for first line of input, what i must to change for other elements? I think i could use (this) but i dont know how. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your class selector is currently only picking up the first element with that class. You'll need to use `this` to find which `.val` is being changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have develop a plugin to accommodate such calculation, try this if it help you

http://www.xsanisty.com/calx/

sample usage for dynamic form can be found here

http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/calx_with_dynamic_form.html

I upload code below to this address: http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/sample/sample.html

```
<form id="form"> 
    <a id="addElement" class="addElement" href="#">Add element</a>

    <div class="position" data-id="1">
        <label for="title">val1</label>
        <input type="text" name="val1[]" class="val1" id="A1">
        <label for="title">val2</label>
        <input type="text" name="val1[]" class="val2" id="B1">

        <span id="C1" class="val3" data-formula="$A1+$B1"></span> 
    </div>

    <p id="all" data-formula="$C1"></p> 
</form>
```

here is the js section

```
<script>
$form = $('#form').calx();

$('#addElement').on('click', function () {
    var lastElem = $('.position').last();
    var newElem = lastElem.clone();
    var data = lastElem.data("id");
    data = data + 1;

    newElem.attr('data-id',data);
    newElem.find('.val1').attr('id','A'+data).val('');
    newElem.find('.val2').attr('id','B'+data).val('');
    newElem.find('.val3').attr('id','C'+data).attr('data-formula','$A'+data+'+$B'+data);
    $('#all').attr('data-formula','SUM($C1,$C'+data+')');

    newElem.insertAfter(lastElem);

    $form.calx('refresh');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is script what i looking for. great. I have one question [my script](http://advice.prohost.pl/test/wystaw.html), i compile to my form but this is only work for fist row. Thanks for reply.

Comment: you miss something in the core.js, in main html you type $('#faktura').calx();, but in the core.js you type $('#form#faktura').calx();, it should refer to the same form

Comment: just replace $form = $('#form#faktura').calx(); to be $form = $('#faktura'); in line 18 and it should works

Comment: Thanks for answer i changed but without results

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue locally, try update your calx script with [this one](http://prototype.xsanisty.com/calx/jquery-calx-1.1.2r1.js)

Comment: I dont know what you do but it's work thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
$('body').on("change",'.val1, .val2',function (event) {
var val1,val2;
if($(this).is(".val1")){
    val1=$(this);
    val2=val1.parent().children(".val2");
}
else{
    val2=$(this);
    val1=val2.parent().children(".val1");
}

    var result = parseFloat(val1.val()) + parseFloat(val2.val());
    result = isNaN(result) ? 0 : result;
    $(this).parent().children('span').text(result.toFixed(2));
    totalQuantity += result;
    $('p').text(totalQuantity);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LK7Tj/8/

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one

```
 $('form').on('change','.val1, .val2',function (event) {
   var result = parseFloat($(this).next("span").text());
   result = isNaN(result) ? 0 : result;
   result = parseFloat($(this).val()) + result;
   $(this).nextAll('span').first().text(result.toFixed(2));
   totalQuantity += parseFloat($(this).val());
   $('p').text(totalQuantity);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LK7Tj/9/

If you are using totalQuantity variable for only this purpose then you should get ride of it and use like this

```
 totalQuantity = parseFloat($("#all").text());
 totalQuantity = isNaN(totalQuantity) ? 0 : totalQuantity;
```

Comment: Working great thanks you very much and thanks to rest for answer

Comment: Cool. I am glad that it worked for you. Can you please approve this answer. Thanks